# Implement custom control using Control Value Accessor by reference to the NgControl

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, controlvalueaccessor, angular-controlvalueaccessor

I have a problem with implementing custom control by reference to the NgControl. It almost works but I have validation problem when I'm calling ngSubmit method. I tried to call form.markAllAsTouched() but with no result.

[Example - Custom Control vs Control from Angular Material](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-udndrf?file=src/app/app.component.html)

**Expected behavior:**

The custom control behaves in the same way as the one from angular material.

Comment: change detection is the reason. Is it ok to remove OnPush from `app-input-text` component?

Comment: Oh god.....It's okey. Thanks!